# Best way to remove specific cookie from the httpservletrequest without using httpservletresponse

Tags: java, servlets, jax-rs

I have one of the jaxrs controller where the requeset is received. The mehtod has 2 parameters like httpservletRequest and clientRequestObj like below. As part of this request we have few cookies and I have to delete on of the cookie from the request and then forward that request some other server but here we don't have httpserveletresponse to remove the cookie and keep it into response.

```
@path("/details")
public Response getDetails(@Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, ConsumerReqBody consumerReqBody) {
    
    
}
```

What is the best way to remove specific cookie from the httpservletrequest without using httpservletresponse.

Comment: FYI: REST requests are specced to be stateless. Cookies are a form of state. You're thus basically violating the REST spec. Simply do not use cookies in first place. You need to take a step back and look for a way to correctly solve the X of your XY-problem.

Comment: Thank you for the response @BaluusC . This is the existing implementation, So we have to do it in this way

Comment: You can inject the response at the class level if you can't change the method parameters. Or just change the parameters if you can

Comment: Do we have any other way that we can achieve without httpservletresponse